# JavaFX and FXML TreeTableView how to change the column/header style

Tags: css, javafx-8, fxml

I am working on this javaFX project and I am trying to change the TreeTableView header or column style such as color, width, font size and etc. I am not able to change style of the header or column. I have try these code but none is working.

> .tree-table-column
>
> .tree-table-column-header
>
> .tree-table-header

**However, I was able to change the row style with this code**

> .tree-table-row-cell

**Does anyone know how to do this?**

Comment: Take a look at the [default CSS](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470) and search for `tree-table`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I will put an answer here for someone who may come across this article.

The appropriate way to set the styling for a tree table view (and this styling guideline is generally how CSS styling of a main components children tends to work) Tree Table View in this case is the parent element so we will write its full name for our css tag, and then list the child element we would like to modify after. See the code below as an example.

```
.tree-table-view .column-header { 
   /* CSS STYLES HERE */
}
.tree-table-view .header {
/* CSS STYLES HERE */
}
.tree-table-view .column {
 /* CSS STYLES HERE */
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful